# Why do we use super() in a python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've come across an example like below,

```
class Model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, dim, batch_sz):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.dim = dim
        self.embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.lstm = LSTM(self.enc_units,
                         recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
```

In this why do we use `super(Encoder, self).__init__()`?. I'm not very familiar with object oriented programming with python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are inhereting from anorther class `class Model(tf.keras.Model):` in the parenthasies here the parent class or *super class* in some cases has to be initialised aswell. Since you have two `__init__` functions to know which one you are accessing the super is used to say use the parent classes `__init__` method.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. Here parent/super class would be `Model()` right? and child class would be `tf.keras.Model`?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-inheritance-in-python-3    I think this describes it better and im more detail than I could.